# Accessing Multiple Lines

Tags: python

Say I have a file:

```
10 5
20 15
30 25
```

How can I access the 20 and the 10 within the same loop to e.g. 20-10 and then 30-20? I.e. the line equivalent of split[0] and split[1] allowing me to use e.g. 10 and 5.

This is probably quite elementary but I'm fairly inexperienced. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried saving the current number in a variable before going to the next line?

Comment: Would that work if the variable would have to continually change?

Comment: `x = line.split()[0]; line = f.readline(); y = line.split()[0]; print x,y`. Repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
last = ''
for line in f:
    x = line.split()[0]
    print last,x
    last = x
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pandas package

```
import pandas
df=pandas.io.parsers.read_csv('amazing_data.csv')

# Optional data plotting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
df.plot(df.Timestamp,linewidth=2.3)
plt.plot()
plt.show()
```

You can access columns using `df[[0]]` or `df[[1]]`

Answer (score 0):

import csv

with open('amazing_data.csv', 'r') as csvfile:

```
reader = csv.reader(a)

for column in zip(*csvfile):

    print column
```